# Unhandled Promise Rejection in React

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have an app that read data from external devices. These data are like acceleration, gyroscopic, magnetometer and pressure.

I'm trying to read the data in this way:

```
async setupNotifications2(device) {
    let i = 0
    const service = this.serviceGeneral();
    while(i<10 ) {
      i++
      const promises = [
        device.readCharacteristicForService(service, this.AccGyrMg),
        device.readCharacteristicForService(service, this.Pressure)
      ]
      Promise.all(promises)
      .then((values) => {
        // const time = new Date().getMilliseconds()
        const time = bufAccGyrMg.readInt16LE(0);
        const [...acc_sx] = [0,2, 4, 6].map(index => bufAccGyrMg.readInt16LE(index));
        this.setState(state => ({acc_sx,array_acc_sx: [...state.array_acc_sx,[time , acc_sx]]}));
        const [...gyr_sx] = [8, 10, 12].map(index => bufAccGyrMg.readInt16LE(index));
        this.setState(state => ({gyr_sx,array_gyr_sx: [...state.array_gyr_sx,[time , gyr_sx]]}));
        const [...mg_sx] = [14,16,18].map(index => bufAccGyrMg.readInt16LE(index));
        this.setState(state => ({gyr_sx,array_mg_sx: [...state.array_mg_sx,[time , mg_sx]]}));
        const bufPressure = Buffer.from(values[1].value, "base64");
        const [...pressure_sx] = [0, 2, 4, 6, 8].map(index => bufPressure.readUInt16LE(index)); 
        this.setState(state => ({pressure_sx,array_pressure_sx: [...state.array_pressure_sx,[time, pressure_sx]]}));

      })

    }
  }
```

Now I have insert a condition inside a while only to try the code.
When I start the app, I receive this error:

YellowBox.js:67 Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
BleError: Operation was rejected

How can I do, in your opinion?? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I refactored your code a bit to help get rid of the `Unhandled Promise Rejection` error and help you point down the issue:

```
async setupNotifications2(device) {
  //first of all, put everything inside a big try/catch block
  try {
    let i = 0
    const service = this.serviceGeneral();
    while(i<10 ) {
      i++
      const promises = [
        // then make sure every promise passed to Promise.all() catches its own errors
        device.readCharacteristicForService(service, this.AccGyrMg).catch( e => console.log(`err in first readCharacteristicForService `, e)),
        device.readCharacteristicForService(service, this.Pressure).catch( e => console.log(`err in second readCharacteristicForService `, e))
      ]
      // giben you're in an async function, you can do this to simplify a bit your code:
        const values = await Promise.all(promises);    
        // const time = new Date().getMilliseconds()
        const time = bufAccGyrMg.readInt16LE(0);
        // this is an array, no need to overcomplicate with destructuring assignment... you can do the same below
        const acc_sx = [0,2, 4, 6].map(index => bufAccGyrMg.readInt16LE(index));
        this.setState(state => ({acc_sx,array_acc_sx: [...state.array_acc_sx,[time , acc_sx]]}));
        const [...gyr_sx] = [8, 10, 12].map(index => bufAccGyrMg.readInt16LE(index));
        this.setState(state => ({gyr_sx,array_gyr_sx: [...state.array_gyr_sx,[time , gyr_sx]]}));
        const [...mg_sx] = [14,16,18].map(index => bufAccGyrMg.readInt16LE(index));
        this.setState(state => ({gyr_sx,array_mg_sx: [...state.array_mg_sx,[time , mg_sx]]}));
        const bufPressure = Buffer.from(values[1].value, "base64");
        const [...pressure_sx] = [0, 2, 4, 6, 8].map(index => bufPressure.readUInt16LE(index)); 
        this.setState(state => ({pressure_sx,array_pressure_sx: [...state.array_pressure_sx,[time, pressure_sx]]}));


} catch (err){
   console.error(`general error: `, err)
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I receive an error:

`Error -  TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined`

Do you know why?

Comment: that's because the second promise (`device.readCharacteristicForService(service, this.Pressure)`) either returns `undefined`, or it crashes.

Comment: you are right, I receive this error first but I don't understand why:
`err1 in first readCharacteristicForService  BleError: Operation was rejected`

Comment: I don't know how to fix that error and I think it would be best to create another question for that, since it seems to be specific to the `device.readCharacteristicForService(...)` method (some Android SDK I assume) and not to javascript. Also, please accept my answer as the correct one, since it helped you pinpoint the actual issue.